# Accessing uploaded files from Django

Tags: python, django, csv, web, file-upload

I am designing a web application that allows the user to upload a .xls file. On upload, the file should be saved, converted to a .csv file, then the data contained in the file will be imported via a python import script.

All of the functions for importing and converting the data are fully functional from within the shell, however when testing via a localhost, the file is converted to .csv and saved but none of the scripts run on the new file.

from views.py:

```
    #for uploading data on the dashboard
    def file_upload(request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            save_path = os.path.join(str(settings.MEDIA_ROOT), 'uploads', str(request.FILES['file']))
            try:
                validate_file_extension(request.FILES['file'])
                path = default_storage.save(save_path, request.FILES['file'])
                data = xls_to_csv(save_path, str(settings.MEDIA_ROOT))
                create_athlete(data, filename)
                create_phase(data)
                create_health_report(data)
                create_workout_report(data)
            except:
                return redirect('polar:dashboard')
            return redirect('polar:dashboard')
```

from importscript.py

```
    def xls_to_csv(file_name, save_path):
        #Formats into pandas dataframe.
        formatted_dataframe = pd.read_excel(file_name, index_col=None)
        #Converts the formatted into a csv file and save it.
        file_name = file_name.replace('.xls', '.csv')
        new_file = formatted_dataframe.to_csv(file_name))
        module_dir = os.path.dirname(settings.BASE_DIR)
        file_path = os.path.join(module_dir, 'uploads', file_name)
        sample_data = open(file_name, 'r')
        unfiltered_data = sample_data.readlines()
        data = unfiltered_data[1:]
        return data
```

It is as if Django is preventing the newly created .csv file from being opened and read from. Any tips on solving this issue would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: what is your current code?

Answer (score 1):

If working on Linux or Mac environment it is important to give the upload directory read and write permission.
Or if that's, not the problem then it seems you have the problem in processing the xls to CSV file  see this one

```
import xlrd
import unicodecsv

def xls2csv (xls_filename, csv_filename):
    # Converts an Excel file to a CSV file.
    # If the excel file has multiple worksheets, only the first 
    #worksheet is converted.
    # Uses unicodecsv, so it will handle Unicode characters.
    # Uses a recent version of xlrd, so it should handle old .xls and 
   # new 
   #.xlsx equally well.

   wb = xlrd.open_workbook(xls_filename)
   sh = wb.sheet_by_index(0)

   fh = open(csv_filename,"wb")
   csv_out = unicodecsv.writer(fh, encoding='utf-8')

   for row_number in xrange (sh.nrows):
       csv_out.writerow(sh.row_values(row_number))

   fh.close()
```

taken from [here](https://www.penwatch.net/cms/excel_to_csv/)

Comment: Unfortunately, I already tried this as did two of my team members on their own computers. It seems to be an issue on the Django side.

Comment: What do you mean by work? Were devolving an app for the athletic department at our university so the data is extremely sensitive as it relates to student athletes and theird private information.

Comment: I meant sample code which I have seen you have already added. let me study your problem and see if I can help?

Comment: try adding in your html  form tag enctype="multipart/form-data"

Comment: That is already in the form. Everything works on the upload side however the issue seems to come in the xls_to_csv function when trying to open the file before feeding it into the create_* functions.

Comment: The sample_data line

Comment: I will try this on monday when I return to work. However I can say that the file is saved as a csv file properly on my local machine and I can even open ans view it. However when trying to open it in the Django view it doesn't open correctly.